# Can not inject activity context to an implementation that is injected in a viewModel

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-hilt

I have an `AppLanguageProvider`which is meant to getting and setting app locale. Obviously it needs context and i tried to inject that context with Dagger-Hilt. While its working fine with getting Locale with application context in the implementation class contructor, i have a problem with setting part. For setting I'm using activity context but when i tried to provide activity context with `@ActivityContext` annotation it throws the exception: `Context Can not be provided without a @Provides annotation`

What I tried:

I tried many combinations to inject and provide that `AppLanguageProvider`for example, I created new hilt module with @ActivityComponent and provided the AppLanguageProvider here but this time it throws an exception:`[Dagger/MissingBinding] com.sevban.tradejournal.core.util.language_provider.AppLanguageProvider cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.` here is the code:

```
@Module
@InstallIn(ActivityComponent::class)
object ActivityModule {

    @Provides
    @ActivityScoped
    fun provideAppLanguageProvider(
        @ActivityContext activity: Context
    ): AppLanguageProvider = AppLanguageProviderImpl(activity)
}

interface AppLanguageProvider {
    fun getAppLanguage() : Language
    fun setAppLanguage(languageCode: String?)
}

@ActivityScoped
class AppLanguageProviderImpl @Inject constructor(
    @ActivityContext private val activity: Context,
) : AppLanguageProvider {
    override fun getAppLanguage(): Language {
        val configuration = activity.resources.configuration
        val locale = Locale.forLanguageTag(configuration.locale.language)
        return when (locale) {
            Locale("tr") -> Language.Turkish
            Locale("en") -> Language.English
            else -> Language.Unknown
        }
    }

    override fun setAppLanguage(languageCode: String?) {
        val locale = Locale(languageCode)
        Locale.setDefault(locale)
        val resources = activity.resources
        val config: Configuration = resources.configuration
        config.setLocale(locale)
        resources.updateConfiguration(config, resources.displayMetrics)
    }
}
```

Another combination:

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object AppModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideAppLanguageProvider(
        @ActivityContext activity: Context
    ): AppLanguageProvider = AppLanguageProviderImpl(activity)
}

class AppLanguageProviderImpl @Inject constructor(
    @ActivityContext private val activity: Context,
) : AppLanguageProvider {
    override fun getAppLanguage(): Language {
        val configuration = activity.resources.configuration
        val locale = Locale.forLanguageTag(configuration.locale.language)
        return when (locale) {
            Locale("tr") -> Language.Turkish
            Locale("en") -> Language.English
            else -> Language.Unknown
        }
    }

    override fun setAppLanguage(languageCode: String?) {
        val locale = Locale(languageCode)
        Locale.setDefault(locale)
        val resources = activity.resources
        val config: Configuration = resources.configuration
        config.setLocale(locale)
        resources.updateConfiguration(config, resources.displayMetrics)
    }
}
```

I also tried to cast application context as activity:

```
override fun setAppLanguage(languageCode: String?) {
   val locale = Locale(languageCode)
   Locale.setDefault(locale)
   val resources = (context as Activity).resources // here
   val config: Configuration = resources.configuration
   config.setLocale(locale)
   resources.updateConfiguration(config, resources.displayMetrics)
}
```

but none of them is working. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
@HiltViewModel
class SettingsViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val authenticator: Authenticator,
) : ViewModel() {
    var lp: AppLanguageProvider? = null
    ...
    
    ...
    //operations with lp
}

interface AppLanguageProvider {
    fun getAppLanguage() : Language
    fun setAppLanguage(languageCode: String?)
}

@ActivityScoped
class AppLanguageProviderImpl @Inject constructor(
    @ActivityContext private val context: Context,
) : AppLanguageProvider {
    override fun getAppLanguage(): Language {
        val configuration = context.resources.configuration
        val locale = Locale.forLanguageTag(configuration.locale.language)
        return when (locale) {
            Locale("tr") -> Language.Turkish
            Locale("en") -> Language.English
            else -> Language.Unknown
        }
    }

    override fun setAppLanguage(languageCode: String?) {
        val locale = Locale(languageCode)
        Locale.setDefault(locale)
        val resources = (context as Activity).resources
        val config: Configuration = resources.configuration
        config.setLocale(locale)
        resources.updateConfiguration(config, resources.displayMetrics)
    }
}


class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    lateinit var navController: NavHostController

    @Inject
    lateinit var appLanguage: AppLanguageProvider

    SetupNavGraph(
    appLanguage = appLanguage,
    navController = navController,
    urlFromIntent = intentString,
    hasUser = hasUser
    )
}


//NavGraph
@Composable
fun SetupNavGraph(
    appLanguage : AppLanguageProvider,
    navController: NavHostController,
    urlFromIntent: String?,
    hasUser: Boolean
) {
composable(ScreenHolder.SettingsScreen.route) {
    val viewModel: SettingsViewModel = hiltViewModel()
    viewModel.lp = appLanguage

    val state by viewModel.state.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()
    val uiText = viewModel.eventChannel
    val eventFlow = viewModel.eventFlow

    SettingsScreen(
        state = state,
        onEvent = viewModel::onEvent,
        onTopBarBackClick = navController::popBackStack,
        uiText = uiText,
        eventFlow = eventFlow,
        navigateAndPopUp = { route ->
            navController.navigate(route) {
                popUpTo(0)
            }
        }
    )
  }
}
```